# Share the same workspace across different jobs

Tags: python, azure-pipelines

Can I share the same workspace installed in one job among other jobs?

In particular, I want to keep share the software installed in one job to later jobs. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#workspace),

> When you run a pipeline on a self-hosted agent, by default, none of the sub-directories are cleaned in between two consecutive runs.

However, this pipeline below failed in job *J2* because the `sphinx` installed in job *J1* is lost in *J2*.

```yaml
jobs:
- job: 'J1'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
  strategy:
    matrix:
      Python37:
        python.version: '3.7'
    maxParallel: 3

  steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
      architecture: 'x64'
  - script: python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    displayName: 'Install dependencies'
  - script: pip install --upgrade pip
    displayName: 'Update pip'
  - script: |
      echo "Publishing document for development version $(Build.BuildId)"
      pip install -U sphinx
    displayName: 'TEST J1'
  - script: |
      echo "TEST SPHINX"
      sphinx-build --help
    displayName: 'TEST SPHINX'

- job: 'J2'
  dependsOn: 'J1'

  steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '3.x'
      architecture: 'x64'

  - script: |
      echo "TEST SPHINX"
      sphinx-build --help
    displayName: 'TEST SPHINX'
```

Answer (score 0):

This error does not relevant with Workspace.

Yes, workspace can be shared across jobs, and on your code, the `sphinx` is also in your workspace. **But**, it is not installed in the `PATH` which is a global path, so while you want to use and execute it later, it failed because the wrong `PATH` value.

In Ubuntu agent, `Pip` installed with `--user` by default. This is a agent user which the agent do not have while you create and using the VM image. If you do not have any change code, it will be installed to the `~/.local/bin` instead of `PATH` by default.

For solved, you need to make sure that the command you are using can be found within `PATH`. If the command is not in your path either include it or use absolute full path to it.

So, you should use **`export`** to specified the PATH value manually:

```
export PATH="xxx"
```

You can check this [blog](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/bin-sh-mkdir-command-not-found/8710) for more details.

Comment: Sounds interesting. However, on the Job named *J1* the `sphinx-build` is correctly added to the path. Also, I tried `command -v sphinx-build` in the first *J1*, and use the absolute path to access `sphinx-build` on the second job *J2*. This test failed as well.

Comment: Could you update how's your path specified and used? It's worked on my side.

Comment: It was specified as `/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.2/x64/bin/sphinx-build`. In fact, the entire pipeline file is here: https://github.com/we-taper/test/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml